# How to solve 405 error on maven build to Nexus 3?

Tags: nexus, sonatype, nexus3

I have created proxy repos in `Nexus 3` pointing to `Nexus 2` hosted repositories. This is to snapshot and release repositories on `Nexus 2`. Now, on `distributionManagement` tag, I am using the proxy URLs and trying do a `mvn clean deploy`. I am getting the following error:

```
[INFO] Error deploying artifact: Failed to transfer file: http://nexus3url/repository/m2-snapshots/path/abc-1.1.4-SNAPSHOT.pom. Return code is: 405

Has anyone tried this?
```

Comment: "I am using the proxy urls"  ... are these proxy repositories? You can only deploy to hosted repositories, you can't deploy to a proxy repository.

Comment: You are correct. Thank you very much for the information. Thanks.

Comment: Are you attempting to Upgrade to Nexus 3? What's your use case here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, you can only deploy to Maven Hosted Repositories, not Proxies. This is by design.

Comment: I've been browsing for a possible solution for the last 5 hours. No one mentions this anywhere else.

Comment: I'll see if I can get that made more explicit.

Comment: Why is this by design? Would you care to elaborate or provide a source?

Comment: Proxies are meant to be a reflection of an upstream repository, so uploading to them doesn't really make sense. Hosted repositories are for uploading your own artifacts. A group would hold a combination of repositories. If you wanted to override an artifact, you'd upload it to a hosted repository, and set that repository to resolve in a group (higher in order) than your proxy. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3):

I faced same issue when I try to deploy application into nexus 3 repository.
In my case the url is not proxy but path was wrong.

If you are trying to deploy snapshot version make sure url pointing to nexus snapshot repository location.
if it is release version url should point to release repository.

Answer (score 0):

Your *Nexus* folder type should be host and try

```
mvn deploy
```

command by using pipeline.

```
configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: '1880060f-32be-4888-a77d-eb046cab6981', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS')]) {
sh "/jenkins_new/jenkins/home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.5.0/bin/mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=net.cyc -DartifactId=${pom.artifactId} -Dversion=${pom.version} -DgeneratePom=true  -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=nbtnexus -Durl=https://dexus.connectcare.net/repository/maven-snapshots/  -DpomFile=pom.xml -Dfile=target/${pom.artifactId}-${pom.version}.${pom.packaging}"                    

    }
```